# can i find a trained deep learning model which comparing two persons image and return if they are the same or not

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

I need a trained deep learning mode can compare two images for two persons and give me the result as if the two image are for the same person or not.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. This is _far_ too broad. We're not here to do your work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you see the face of the two persons on the image. In this case you can try to use **Facenet**  [Paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.03832)

You can find an implementation for example here [link](https://github.com/davidsandberg/facenet)